# How to limit the height of table row to 3 lines?

Tags: html, css

I want to limit the height of row in a table to maximun 3 lines if the cell contains a long characters

[Here a picture that shows the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPQ1W.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a set `max-height` style on the tr and do an `overflow` of a `scroll` if you want to enable the user to scroll. Example:

```
table td {
    max-height: 3em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Its doesnt work , and I dont want to make the scroll

Comment: @AbdessamadMellas Well it does depend on where you add it, I can't see your code. But here is an example here http://jsfiddle.net/SpqnW/1/ and if you want to add see more or something awesome to add it It I would go with http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/9t3Z5/3/

Comment: I uploaded a picture that shows what I want,  , Can you make it in a table for me ?